# UnmanagedExports Function Parameters - Cause VBA 49 Bad DLL Calling Convention

Tags: c#, excel, dllexport, function-parameter, unmanagedexports

I am unable to get my C# Dll to work with my Excel Macro enable spreadsheet to call the function in the Dll. I am able to call the function if it has no parameters, able to return the expected value. But I cannot get the Dll call from VBA to be successful when I add input parameters to the function.

The sum total of my C# module is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace RSExternalInterface
{
    public class RSExternalInterface
    {
        [DllExport("add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }
    }
}
```

My VBA Code is as follows.

Module Declaration:

```
Declare Function add Lib "C:\Program Files\RS\RSExternalInterface.dll" (ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Right as Integer) As Integer
```

Call the function above, inside the click event sub of a button,  is as follows:

```
result = add (5, 7)
```

The moment the above line is executed, Error 49 comes up.

I have tried the following:

1. Removed the "ByVal" in the VBA function declaration
2. Removed and added the decoration in the C# function, after [DllExports ...]
3. Ensured that I target the correct CPU platform
4. Removed the parameters in the declaration and calling to ensure that the DLL function is accessible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need to type `Lib` after `add`

Comment: The Lib is indeed in my code. Typo for not adding it in above. Corrected.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `As Integer` from your declarations? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Check your *C#* *.dll* with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com), and see if the exported function(s) is/are shown. I copy/pasted your exact code, but my *.dll* doesn't seem to export anything. Loading the func from *VBasic* fails (obviously), as it can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that "*Calling Convention*" from question title and `CallingConvention` from *C#* code didn't ring any bell (although I don't rule out a misleading error message on *MS* side).

Calling convention is like a protocol when executing subroutines, between:

- *callee* - the routine (function, procedure (or function that doesn't return anything, or returns `void`))
- *caller* - code (a subroutine as well - could be `main`) that calls/executes the *callee*

and determines:

1. Who handles (*push* / *pop*) the function arguments on the stack (*callee* / *caller*) when executing it
2. Arguments order on the stack (*right -> left* or *left -> right*)

Because of *#1.*, it's important that the 2 parties (*callee* / *caller*) **to be in synch** regarding calling convention, otherwise they will setp on each other's toes, and the stack will eventually get corrupted. "*Bad DLL Calling Convention*" means exactly this thing: the 2 are **not** in synch.

- You get correct behavior for function without arguments, because there's nothing to *push* / *pop* to/from the stack - **this doesn't mean that there isn't any error**; the error is there but it's not encountered
- More details: [[MSDN]: Argument Passing and Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58(v=vs.140).aspx). Note differences between `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`, and also note that they apply to **32bit (*x86*)  architecture**. *AFAIK* (also backed up by the error), *Excel* executable (as whole *MSOffice*) is 32bit
- According to [[MSDN]: DllImportAttribute.CallingConvention Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention(v=vs.140).aspx) (which I assume also applies to `DllExport`):

  > You set this field to one of the [CallingConvention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration members. The default value for the CallingConvention field is [Winapi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx), which in turn defaults to [StdCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx) convention.

I took your code, and played a little bit with it.

*code.cs*:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;


namespace RSExternalInterface
{
    public class RSExternalInterface
    {
        [DllExport("add")]
        public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
        {
            int ret = left + right;
            String s = String.Format("C# Func - add: {0} + {1} = {2}", left, right, ret);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return ret;
        }

        [DllExport("dbl", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        public static int TestExport1(int value)
        {
            int ret = value * 2;
            String s = String.Format("C# Func - dbl: {0} * 2 = {1}", value, ret);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return ret;
        }

        [DllExport("none", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void TestExport2(int value)
        {
            String s = String.Format("C# Func - none: {0}", value);
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }
}
```

*main.vb*:

```
Module main

    Declare Function add Lib "CsDll.dll" (ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Right As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Function dbl Lib "CsDll.dll" (ByVal Value As Integer) As Integer
    Declare Sub none Lib "CsDll.dll" (ByVal Value As Integer)

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("64 bit OS: {0}{1}64 bit process: {2}{1}", Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem, Environment.NewLine, Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        Dim i As Integer
        none(-7659)
        i = dbl(78)
        i = add(22, -13)

    End Sub

End Module
```

**Notes**:

- I wasn't able to build it and run it in *Excel*, so I tried the 2<sup>nd</sup> best thing: do it from *VB*. Note that I'm experienced in neither *C#* nor *VB*
- At the beginning (as I stated in a comment), I wasn't able to export anything from the *C#* *.dll*. Looking at *UnmanagedExports.nuspec* (part of the *nupkg*):

  > - You have to set your platform target to either x86, ia64 or x64. AnyCPU assemblies cannot export functions.
- Changed the *Platform* from *Any CPU* (*VStudio* default) to *x64* (by mistake), and everything ran fine (in spite of `CallingConvention.Cdecl`), only after setting it to *x86* I was able to reproduce the problem
- Anyway, the (*C#*) code contains 3 ways of (not) specifying a calling convention, that will work from *VB*

**Output** (*VStudio 2015 (Community)*):

> ```
> 64 bit OS: True
> 64 bit process: False
>
> C# Func - none: -7659
> C# Func - dbl: 78 * 2 = 156
> C# Func - add: 22 + -13 = 9
> ```

Here's an (ancient) *URL* that also mentions your error: [[MSDN]: Bad DLL calling convention (Error 49)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232602(v=vs.60).aspx)